# Deployed Keter App Logs Users Out With a New Keter Bundle

Tags: haskell, yesod

Keter has been awesome so far.  For my little toy project, I used to create the keter bundle on the production server and push it keter's incoming directory and everything worked fine.

Now I wanted to learn how to setup a staging environment and so I tried compiling my bundle on staging server (it is an image copy of the production server). When I push this bundle to my production server (via scp), it logs out signed-in users. The app itself is fine after logging back in.

What has changed:

- Some templating code has changed but nothing drastic and such changes were fine when compiled on the production server before
- Yesod's settings.yml changed to use the staging server's IP address for development testing
- Keter.yaml was not modified.

What am I doing wrong? Why does Keter care where my .keter bundle was created? Is there a way to create these bundles without disrupting signed-in users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the issue is that a new client_session_key file is being created each time your app is being deployed. Instead, you need to generate a key file once and reuse it. This is generally handled correctly by the Yesod scaffolded site, but providing an implementation of `makeSessionBackend` that stores the key file in `config`.

What is your current implementation of `makeSessionBackend`? And do your keter bundles include a file `config/client_session_key.aes`?

Comment: Wow you are incredible! I unpacked my Keter bundle (old and new) and I indeed see different content inside client_session_key.aes! I am using a scaffolded site and it has this code `makeSessionBackend _ = fmap Just $ defaultClientSessionBackend (7 * 24 * 60 * 60) "config/client_session_key.aes"`. How should I change it? Is the default value somehow tied to the hostname that the production server consistently re-generated the same key?

Comment: Never mind. Found the issue! I have the `aes file` in my `.gitignore` so it does not get pushed to the staging server. I will just manually copy it when I need to create the bundle. Thanks for pointing the issue out!